# Would setting a collection to null after assigning it to an itemssource clear up resources?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, collections, garbage-collection

I was doing some performance optimization inside my app and there were a lot of places where I'm assigning a collection to the itemssource property of a listbox. When I assign the collection to the listbox is the original collection disposed from memory. If not, by setting it to null will it mark the collection for garbage collection?

For example:

```
void myWebServiceCompleted(object sender, List<Item> itemList)
{
    ItemListBox.ItemsSource = itemList;
    //Would setting itemList = null clear up resources?
}
```

I was just concerned because this type of assignment is made in multiple places in the app and if the above is true that means twice the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

the ListBox holds a reference to your original list, so it is not garbage collected.
If for whatever reason you wanted the original list to get collected, you could manually add ListItems to the ListBox.

In this case the original list could get collected as long as there were no other references.

I guess this would be useful if each of the items in your collection was resource-heavy, and the listbox only needed to know a couple of fields (name and id for example)

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not. itemList is a reference type. It's not duplicated like you think it is. Instead, you just have multiple references to it. It's like receiving multiple letters in the mail with the same address on them. It doesn't mean the house with that address is duplicated, just that there are multiple addresses referring to the same house.

As long as one rooted object still refers to your collection, it will not be freed by the garbage collector. Setting itemList to null has no effect on the total space consumed by this collection.

> I was just concerned because this type of assignment is made in multiple places in the app and that means twice the memory.

It does not mean that. I strongly encourage you to drop everything you're doing and read about reference types until you understand this incredibly important point.

I now understand why Joel Spolsky thinks every programmer should learn C.